# Using IBM Cloudant with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cloudant

I am trying to connect to my free IBM Cloudant instance using SQLAlchemy but I'm unsure of the notation and I keep getting errors.

I've tried the following but it returns the error `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:cloudant`.

```
engine = create_engine(f"cloudant:///?User={USER}&; Password={PASSWORD}", echo=True)
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Found out Cloudant is a NoSQL CouchDB so SQLAlchemy won't work as Cloudant is not a relational database (with tables, etc.) but made of JSON documents. If you want to use Cloudant, you need to use the Cloudant Python SDK (https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant?code=python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy does not have built-in support either for IBM Cloudant itself, or for the CouchDB platform on which it is based. The [list of external dialects for SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/index.html#external-dialects) also makes no mention of either database. So it appears that there is no "officially recognized" dialect for IBM Cloudant at the moment.

That said, a web search for "sqlalchemy cloudant" did find this:

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cloudant-python-sqlalchemy.rst

(The above link is for information purposes only. It is not an endorsement.)